# Mongo sort performance date vs _id vs timestamp / find vs aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In terms of performance (pure speed, don't care for now about ram usage) is there a "big" difference between sorting a collection by a date, a number (timestamp) or an _id ?

In addition is there a difference in performance between find and aggregate ?

I have already all the index necessary and i project/select only needed fields :)

Comment: i think a simple way, is to to test it your self, create a big collection, and do the benchmark. If you can tell us also the results. To not include the transfer time you can do a `$limit` 1, or `$out` so few data come to client

Comment: You can generate a _query plan_ for each the cases you want to test - using the `explain` method and compare the results yourself. Query plan can show the details like the index(es) used for an operation like filter or sort or both, time taken, etc. Make sure you run the `explain` using the "executionStats" mode.

Comment: haha i know i can do it by myself, but i would prefer that someone already did ! :D